# How to use callbacks in a has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, has-many-through

I have a Task model associated to a Project model via has_many through and need to manipulate the data before delete/insert via the association.

Since "[Automatic deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are triggered.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)" i can not use callbacks for this.

In Task i need all project_ids to calculate a value for Project after Task is saved.
How can i disable delete or change delete to destroy on has_many through association?
What is best practise for this problem?

```
class Task
  has_many :project_tasks
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_tasks

class ProjectTask
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :task

class Project
  has_many :project_tasks
  has_many :tasks, :through => :project_tasks
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Seems like i have to use [associations callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) `before_add`, `after_add`, `before_remove` or `after_remove`

```
class Task
  has_many :project_tasks
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_tasks, 
                      :before_remove => :my_before_remove, 
                      :after_remove => :my_after_remove
  protected

  def my_before_remove(obj)
    ...
  end

  def my_after_remove(obj)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Want to note that I ran into some issues using Database transactions in union with these callbacks. I may not be using transactions correctly, but exceptions in these callbacks won't rollback the parent record's save/destroy transactions.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did

in the model:

```
class Body < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hands, dependent: destroy
  has_many :fingers, through: :hands, after_remove: :touch_self
end
```

in my Lib folder:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
  private
    def touch_self(obj)
      obj.touch && self.touch
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating joins model associations, Rails add and remove records on the collection. To remove the records, Rails use the `delete` method and this one will not call any [destroy callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object).

You can force Rails to call `destroy` instead `delete` when is removing records.
To do that, install the gem [replace_with_destroy](https://rubygems.org/gems/replace_with_destroy) and pass the option `replace_with_destroy: true` to the **has_many** association.

```
class Task
  has_many :project_tasks
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_tasks,
            replace_with_destroy: true
  ...
end

class ProjectTask
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :task

  # any destroy callback in this model will be executed
  #...

end

class Project
  ...
end
```

With this, you ensure Rails invoke all the [destroy callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object). This could be very useful if you are using [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like adding `dependent: :destroy` to `has_many :through` relation will destroy the join model (instead of delete). This is because [CollectionAssociation#delete](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L188) internally refers to `:dependent` option to determine whether the passed records should be deleted or destroyed.

So in your case,

```rb
class Task
  has_many :project_tasks
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_tasks, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

should work.