# Rails 4 form - creating record in one table and update record in another. How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As in subject - how to do it ? I did some research over the internet but all solutions i found was either not working or unclear for me. Maybe i'm just miserable searcher.
Anyway, this is the case:

I have two tables: events and participants. All field are pretty standard for purpose, but i have also this less-obvious fields: 'captaken' in event and 'amount' in participant.
Basic idea is that every participant specify number of people to sign up for event (eg. smbdy will come with wife or gf, so 'amout' is 2). And every event has limited number of participant - current amount of taken seats is stored in 'captaken' field.

I have simple scaffolded form for adding participant, and the goal is to make 'captaken' field of specify event increment according to 'amount' each time new participant is signing up (creating).

How could i make it happen ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597878/howto-use-callbacks-in-a-has-many-through-association

Comment: I was aware about callbacks in general, I just didn't know how to make proper use of (for example) them in that particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use after_create callback in participant model. 
which will work as Whenever new record is created in participants update the value In another table.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Do I need any assurements or settings on the side of event table to get it work ?

Comment: No just add after_create : update_event . And write code to update event value in  this update_event  method. What is the association between participant and event ?

Comment: Participant belongs to event

Comment: So code will be like :  in participant model. after_ create :update_event

Comment: I'm afraid i did something wrong. In my update_event in participant model i did: self.event.captaken += self.amount
And nothing happens, what i did wrong ?

Comment: Change like this.          event.update_attribute(:captaken => self.event.captaken + self.amount) end

Comment: Sorry for not formatting data properly. Actually I am not able to format comments from my phone. Btw did I help u in solving it ?

Comment: Yup :)) Thanks a lot, you solved my problem. Just little notice: I needed to did (:captaken, self.event.captaken....) ',' instead of '=>'
And how do rails know which event is 'event' ??

Comment: Actually in model callbacks. It applies self by itself. If I am writing event. Ror understands it as self.event only. As we have such association.

Comment: Great. I hate to do things without understanding. Kudos for explanation, patience, and your time. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest possible way to do it in your participant model:

```
#Specify the relationship, model should have an event_id field.

belongs_to :event

#This is the hook to tell the system to update the event
#after creation.

after_create :update_event_captaken


#Method for updating the event

def update_event_captaken
  self.event.captaken += self.amount
  self.event.save
end
```

Comment: Altough my problem is solved already, your example shows me why my own attempts to get it done failed. I never did .save!
Thanks for that :)