# when does the destroy action actually destroy the item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While working on a fairly complicated 'update certain items in a queue' method, I need to depend on the collection length becoming shorter after I destroy one of its members.

But when I do this...

```
def destroy # destroying a unit_user
    @unit = @unituser.unit

    logger.info('----- queue length before destroy is ' + @unit.unit_users.length.to_s)

    if @unituser.destroy
      logger.info('---- queue length after destroy is ' + @unit.unit_users.length.to_s)
```

... the logger prints the same value twice!

So why, even though the action *does* eventually destroy the unituser, the queue length doesn't shorten when I expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is essentially because the collection (in this case, the `@unit.unit_users` collection) is cached (meaning, the association query is not re-executed every time you call it). One way to solve this is to "reload" the model after destroying the record.

After destroying the record, simply do this:

```
@unit.reload
```

This will re-execute the original query which first loaded `@unit`.

Afterwards, your `@unit.unit_users` collection should show a different size by this point.

**Update**

I'm realizing now that given the names of your models, it looks like you have a many to many between a `Unit` and `User` model, with a join model called `UnitUser`. If that is the case, and you simply want remove the association, but keep the unit and user objects, you can do something like this instead:

```
@unit.unit_users.destroy(@some_user_object)
```

Comment: But when you destroy a member of a collection the local cached collection is updated I'd guess? It's been a long time since I touched Rails, but I don't think you have to reload each time you deleted something(?).

Comment: @Mörre It depends what you actually want to delete. If, for example, you simply want to remove an object from a many to many collection, but want both objects to remain, then you can do something like `@unit.unit_users.destroy(@user)`. That in case the unit and user will remain, but the `@unit.unit_users` collection will be properly updated without needing to reload. I'm actually now thinking that the OPs scenario might actually be a M-M, so I'll add that in. But otherwise, if you are destroying the dependent object entirely AND removing from the collection, I believe this is the only way.

Comment: @Mörre If you or anyone finds something that indicates I'm wrong though, by all means let me know. I don't want to give the OP incorrect information. Keep in mind too that I think this is an odd scenario; to do something in a RESTful delete action that is based on the size of the association collection after deletion is arguably a bit strange, and this might be an XY problem.

Comment: I could not tell if you are correct or not because I don't quite understand OPs problem, I miss quite a bit of context - but then, as I said, it's been some time since I used Rails.

Comment: @unit.reload worked great - thanks! ....also, an after_destroy callback would probably be the best way to do what I intend, but I had trouble there as well and wanted to get the logic working in the controller first.

Comment: @dwilbank Cool, glad it helped. It was probably the same problem in the `after_destroy` callback I'm guessing; you would have had to reload it there as well. You might be interested in the [association callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) as well. I'm not sure what it is specifically you're trying to do, but the `after_remove` on the `has_many` relationship might serve your purposes nicely. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10600442/877472) has a demonstration of this.