# How to access the updated object in a javascript callback (instead of the old object)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

Building on the helpful and working solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788898/when-does-the-destroy-action-actually-destroy-the-item), I'm trying to fix my update callback as well.

Problem is, the specific `unit` that I'm trying to extract data from is always the old cached version, even though this callback is triggered by a successful `update` action.

```
// callback triggered by the update action

$('.best_in_place').bind("ajax:success", function () {
   ...
    console.log(unit.duration);
    // which is exactly the same as
    console.log(<%= Unit.find(unit.id).unit_users.pluck(:duration).sum %>);
    // and both print the OLD duration val instead of the updated val which is in the database
});
```

and the unit_users_controller code...

```
  def update
    @unit = @unituser.unit

    respond_to do |format|
      if @unituser.update(unit_user_params)
        @unit.reload
        logger.info('-----------------------------------------------------------------')
        logger.info('@unit.duration in the controller is ' + @unit.duration.to_s) # which is the correct value
        logger.info('-----------------------------------------------------------------')
        gon.unit_duration = @unit.duration # an experiment which didn't work for me
        format.json {respond_with_bip(@unituser) }
      else
        # format.html { render :action => 'edit' }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@unituser) }
      end
    end
  end
```

I've tried several versions of `unit.reload`, and nothing helps. Maybe I was putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: can you post the controller code?

Comment: @RodrigoZurek Unrelated to controller code. The controller has nothing to do with this. This is about misunderstanding how `.js.erb` files work.

Comment: it has to do with the controller, if you want the updated object it has to go through the controller and you have to get it back somehow

Comment: @RodrigoZurek The correct solution would, yes. Showing the controller code isn't relevant because the controller code isn't the issue. The issue is misuse of `<%= %>` in the view.

Comment: pasted in my controller code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this one sometime ago here is my code, maybe it will help you:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.price_bind').bind("ajax:success", function (event, data, status, xhr) {
      var parsed_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      $(this).text(parsed_data.newprice);
      $(this).parentsUntil('body').find(".totalpricep span").text(parsed_data.totalprice);
  });
}
```

View:

```
<%= best_in_place detail, :price, :classes => 'price_bind', :path => purchase_detail_path(@purchase, detail)%>
```

Controller:

```
 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @detail.update_attributes(params[:detail])
        @n=@detail.mk_bal
        @r=false
        if @detail.purchase != nil
          @p=@detail.purchase.totalprice
        if params[:detail]['status'] && @purchase.step==1
          @remdet = @purchase.details.where(:step => 1, :status => false)
          if @remdet.empty?
            @purchase.update_attribute(:step, 2)
            @r=true
          end  
        end
        else
          @p=nil
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @detail, notice: 'Detail was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :json => {:newprice => @n, :totalprice => @p, :newstatus => @detail.status, :refresh => @r}}
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: but your format.json doesn't have the {respond_with_bip(@unituser) } in it, which I thought was mandatory if you wanted the field to update. ??

Comment: The object is being updated before the respond right here: @detail.update_attributes(params[:detail]), or any other update you want. After that you can respond from your controller however you want, in this case it expects a JSON response and you can return whatever aspect of the new object you want

Comment: so format.json { render :json => {:unit_duration => @unit.duration.to_s }} certainly gets me the data I need, but my best_in_place field shows the wrong data now. Is there any way to combine the above render with the previous format.json {respond_with_bip(@unituser) } so I have the best of both worlds?

Comment: that is the javascript part on my answer, once the request has succeded you replace the value you got from your controller, and replace it on the view.

 $(this).parentsUntil('body').find(".totalpricep span").text(parsed_data.totalprice);

Comment: okay - I think I got it. You're ignoring the respond_with_bip helper and rebuilding its functionality yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about caching. Your Ruby code is evaluated **server**-side, before the JavaScript is ever send to the client, and it's only evaluated once, long before the AJAX request can happen.

The client never sees this line:

```
console.log(<%= Unit.find(unit.id).unit_users.pluck(:duration).sum %>);
```

All the client will see is something like:

```
console.log(32); // or whatever the sum is
```

You cannot use `<%= %>` here. That will always give you the original value. Instead, you need to send the new value to the client in response to the AJAX request.

Comment: Woops - that Unit.find was a late night stupidity. It's more clear now. Thanks!