# Rails has_many using association ids not calling callback on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The `after_commit` callback is not being triggered when the `has_many` relationship is updated and a record is destroyed.

I have a relationship

```
class Expertise
  has_many :doctor_expertises
  has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_expertises

class DoctorExpertise
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :expertise

  after_commit :do_something

  def do_something
     # not called when record destroyed 
  end
```

in my controller I use the following method to update the `has_many` relationship

```
  def create
    doc = DoctorProfile.find(params[:doctor_id])
    doc.expertise_ids = params[:expertise_ids].select do |x|
      x.to_i > 0
    end
    doc.save!

    render json: doc.expertises
  end
```

I understand that I should be using `update` and `destroy` on the relationship. However, why is `after_commit` not getting called on a record when it is destroyed?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I'm setting `doc.expertise_ids` not triggering the callback. However I'm unable to find any documentation about this method except for briefly [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference). Is there documentation that confirms or denies this suspicion or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the RailsGuides that you linked:

**Automatic deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are triggered.**

Although it doesn't state about after_commit it's quite likely that isn't being fired too

I think the answer you are looking for is here:

[Howto use callbacks in a has_many through association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597878/howto-use-callbacks-in-a-has-many-through-association)

You need to user after_remove within the has_many declaration

Answer (score 1):

Updating joins model associations, Rails add and remove records on the collection. To remove the records, Rails use the `delete` method and this one will not call any [destroy callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object).

**Solution 1**

One way to invoke some callbacks when add or remove association is using [Association Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks).

```
class Expertise
  has_many :doctor_expertises
  has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_expertises
           before_remove: :my_before_remove,
           after_remove: my_after_remove           

  def my_before_remove(doctor_profile)
    ...
  end

  def my_after_remove(doctor_profile)
    ...
  end
end
```

**Solution 2**

Force Rails call `destroy` instead `delete` when is removing records.
To do that, install the gem [replace_with_destroy](https://rubygems.org/gems/replace_with_destroy) and pass the option `replace_with_destroy: true` to the **has_many** association.

```
class Expertise
  has_many :doctor_expertises
  has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_expertises,
            replace_with_destroy: true        
  ...
end

class DoctorExpertise
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :expertise

  after_commit :do_something

  def do_something
     # this will be called when updating Expertise.doctor_profiles
     # because use destroyed instead delete to remove the record
  end
```

With this, you ensure Rails invoke all the [destroy callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `dependent: :destroy` like so

`has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_expertises, dependent: :destroy`

I know it's somewhat misleading to have dependent destroy on has_many through, but it will trigger destroy callback and it will not destroy the base records, just the join records. Reference: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/issues/246